# Find duplicated records in a file and output them in another file

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file in unix with 4 columns like below:

```
date1 2037 account1 5000    
date2 2037 account1 5003    
date3 2037 account1 5007    
date4 2037 account1 5009    
date5 2037 account2 5000    
date6 2037 account2 5003    
date7 2037 account2 5007    
date8 2037 account2 5009
..
```

I want  to find all the `account1` (values on 3rd column) which have all the `5000, 5003, 5007, 5009` values.
If possible I would like to put it in another file like below:

date1 2037 account1 5000 date2 2037 account1 5003 ...

date4 2037 account2 5000 date9 2037 account2 5003 ..

..
Any help will be valuable.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this line a try:

```
awk '{a[$3]=a[$3]?a[$3]FS$NF:$0}END{for(x in a)print a[x]}' file
```

with your example data, it outputs:

```
date1 2037 account1 5000 5003 5007 5009
date5 2037 account2 5000 5003 5007 5009
```

Comment: It works, can you modify it to output 
date1 2037 account1 5000 date2 2037 account1 5003 ...

date4 2037 account2 5000 date9 2037 account2 5003 ..

Comment: @AlexincoAlex to achieve that, you change `$NF` in my code into `$0`

Answer (score 0):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '!b[$3]++{c[++j]=$3} {a[$3]=a[$3]?a[$3] OFS $NF:$0} END{for(i=1;i<=j;i++){print a[c[i]]}}'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
date1 2037 account1 5000 5003 5007 5009
date5 2037 account2 5000 5003 5007 5009
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if the file is already sorted by 3rd field(*account*):

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s",(acc? ($3!=acc? ORS:FS) : ""),$0 }{ acc=$3 }END{ print }' file
```

The output:

```
date1 2037 account1 5000 date2 2037 account1 5003 date3 2037 account1 5007 date4 2037 account1 5009
date5 2037 account2 5000 date6 2037 account2 5003 date7 2037 account2 5007 date8 2037 account2 5009date8 2037 account2 5009
```